# FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, When ever i am trying to popluate some value from opportunity to case

Tags: apex

When i am trying to update some value from opporunity to case thorogh task trigger which run from opportunity task, i am getting below error. I checked on opporunity/case,  we have no lookup filter defined. Please guide guidelines for debugging, logs are not showing anything which i can look

I am only doing somethign

Line 50 is   caseobject.my_SalesRep__c=opp.Sales_Rep__c,

```
 Review all error messages below to correct your data.
    Apex trigger TaskTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: TaskTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, The person selected must be a Sales Rep: [my_SalesRep__c]: Class.TaskTriggerHandler.evaluateIfReadyForUnderwritingSingle: line 50, column 1
```

Comment: There should be lookup filter criteria on Case object. It seems the field (caseobject.my_SalesRep__c) belongs to a Case object.

Comment: @Thanks Devendra for quick responce...,Yes that field on case object, but there is no look filter on case object.. I went through setup>case>lookup filter ,but nothing is there on that field

Comment: Enter the field itself in the SF UI and you should see it. the `The person selected must be a Sales Rep` message is a custom fillter-validation error.

Comment: @David Navigate to Case fields and Click on the Field Label for my_SalesRep__c and review the detail page to see if any filters exist.

Comment: If this is custom error,, then how can i know from where this is cooming...i have gone through all validation rules on task, opportunity,case nothing is there. I went through full app apex classes and trigger to look for addError method but this error is not there

Comment: No filter exist on details page for case and that field my_SalesRep__c

Comment: @Thanks Devendra and Yonatan..i got the filter now..yes that is on field

Comment: @David Glad it worked for you !

Comment: One of you please post as answer .So we can close this thread

Comment: Yes this thread can be close..Solution was actually profile filter was there..I just gave the right user with that profile, and resolved the error. That was data issue. Thanks All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to Case fields and Click on the Field Label for my_SalesRep__c and review the detail page to see if any filters exist.

1. Go to Setup | Customize | Case | Fields.
2. Scroll through your Standard and Custom Fields until you find a Lookup Field.
3. Click on the Field Label and review the detail page to see if any filters exist.
4. Review the Filter Criteria to be sure your modifications adhere to it.